# Mysql Select Where IN Unknown column

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I'm having some problem with mysql code in phpmyadmin. I want to run this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ID
IN (
38b5f138683c57ccb1d5beec62284d8f, 08dcd7bf2fb5dc6d73d114c84c252393, bda3a36a9392a91f9142e0442e24bf24, 38963779bc562e388cbf702d6f0189cc, 98989c3c20be63f856d48a3f0584b85e
)
```

but I received this error: `#1054 - Unknown column '38b5f138683c57ccb1d5beec62284d8f' in 'where clause'`

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to the possible causes of this error?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN ( "38b5f138683c57ccb1d5beec62284d8f", "08dcd7bf2fb5dc6d73d114c84c252393", "bda3a36a9392a91f9142e0442e24bf24", "38963779bc562e388cbf702d6f0189cc", "98989c3c20be63f856d48a3f0584b85e" )
```